# Lambda Python request athena error OutputLocation

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-athena

I'm working with AWS Lambda and I would like to make a simple query in athena and store my data in an s3.

My code :

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    query_1 = "SELECT * FROM test_athena_laurent.stage limit 5;"
    database = "test_athena_laurent"
    s3_output = "s3://athena-laurent-result/lambda/"

    client = boto3.client('athena')

    response = client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString=query_1,
    ClientRequestToken='string',
    QueryExecutionContext={
        'Database': database
    },
    ResultConfiguration={
        'OutputLocation': 's3://athena-laurent-result/lambda/'
    }
    )
    return response
```

It works on spyder 2.7 but in AWS I have this error :

```
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid length for parameter ClientRequestToken, value: 6, valid range: 32-inf: ParamValidationError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 18, in lambda_handler
    'OutputLocation': 's3://athena-laurent-result/lambda/'
```

I think that It doesn't understand my path and I don't know why.

Thanks

Comment: *"Parameter validation failed - Invalid length for parameter ClientRequestToken"* is pretty unambiguous, as far as error messages are concerned. Maybe `'string'` is not the right value for this parameter.

Comment: Thanks, it's my error. Do you know where I can find ClientRequestToken ?

Comment: I delete ClientRequestToken like in spyder. In spyder it work but in AWS It doesn't. May be I do not have the rights. `ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartQueryExecution`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Tomalak's point `ClientRequestToken` is a [string](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_StartQueryExecution.html). However, per the documentation I just linked, you don't need it anyway when using the SDK.

> This token is listed as not required because AWS SDKs (for example the AWS SDK for Java) auto-generate the token for users. If you are not using the AWS SDK or the AWS CLI, you must provide this token or the action will fail.

So, I would refactor as such:

```
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    query_1 = "SELECT * FROM some_database.some_table limit 5;"
    database = "some_database"
    s3_output = "s3://some_bucket/some_tag/"

    client = boto3.client('athena')

    response = client.start_query_execution(QueryString = query_1,
                                        QueryExecutionContext={
                                            'Database': database
                                        },
                                        ResultConfiguration={
                                            'OutputLocation': s3_output
                                        }
                                        )
    return response
```

Answer (score 2):

> ClientRequestToken (string) --
>   A **unique case-sensitive string used to ensure the request to create the query is idempotent** (executes only once). If another StartQueryExecution request is received, the same response is returned and another query is not created. If a parameter has changed, for example, the QueryString , an error is returned. [[Boto3 Docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution)]

**This field is autopopulated if not provided.**

If you are providing a string value for `ClientRequestToken`, ensure it is [within length limits from `32` to `128`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_StartQueryExecution.html#API_StartQueryExecution_RequestSyntax).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs, very helpful. I was looking at boto3 docs and it's not there. The error message i get is `Invalid length for parameter ClientRequestToken, value: 28, valid range: 32-inf` which implies 32 until `infinitiy`