# How do Lambda query Athena by python

Tags: python, lambda

I'm try using python write one `Lambda function`. In the function I want to query Athena, and the return results shall be as Rows as normal SQL query result.
I try to using boto3, `create_named_query()` and `get_query_results()`,but it not works.

Anyone can be provide one example, I will be very appreciate, thank you again.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages, code that you used would also be helpful!

Comment: I see more demo using client.start_query_execution, but I don't want to provide s3

Comment: @JosephBywater thank you. Using method create_named_query, I can get its NamedQueryId, but when I using NamedQueryId in method get_query_results ,its response show NamedQueryId  was not found. And I want to know how does the lambda know which region athena I want to query

Comment: Please share a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Harvey, you need to provide an output location for an Athena query, even if you read the results directly into your code.  [Lambda Python request athena error OutputLocation
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551305/lambda-python-request-athena-error-outputlocation/47559999#47559999)

Comment: @Zerodf thanks. Current I can execute start_query_execution and it output resultset into s3 in later. But I want to return resultset after execute start_query_execution. I don't want to using waiting in method, hope resultset can be returned in one method. Do you have any good comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification.  You have three options.

1. Use a [third party library](https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthenaJDBC) to execute against Athena (uploading using a [deployment package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)) and read the results directly into your code within your Lambda Function.
2. Execute the desired SQL query and read the results directly from S3 from within your Lambda Function.
3. Create two Lambda functions.  One to kick off the query and the other to read from the results.  The second can be triggered whenever a new file is created in the destination S3 bucket used by Athena.

Consider the following (2018-06-09):

1. [Lambda Maximum Execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) Duration is 300 seconds.
2. Athena currently has a [maximum query duration of 1800 seconds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/service-limits.html).

Therefore, unless you can absolutely guarantee that query execution will occur in under 300 seconds, 3 is the only viable option.  Also, three is the most scaleable option, as you can fire off a new processing run for every query output you create.

Comment: Thanks. Current I using the second way.Add one loop check executed result. It says there exist one Waiter can check.But after installed athena-cli, it still don't works.Anyway,current function works.https://github.com/boto/botocore/pull/1358 
 https://github.com/boto/botocore/pull/1358/commits/1af707240f73f86c9d01d7fab5ab6f132737658c?diff=split

Comment: github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1212
 # waiter = client.get_waiter('query_succeeded')
 Response is cannot get waiter